# Compilation error when using @RequestMapping - Cannot resolve type

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

IDE : Spring Tool Suite
pom.xml

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have added the MVC dependency as org.springframework but I guess it has to be org.springframework.boot.

I get this Compilation error when using @RequestMapping - Cannot resolve type.

I have run Maven -> clean and Maven -> Install. Restarted STS, re-installed STS, rebooted my laptop, and yet the compilation error persists. 
How do I remove this error?

**Update**:

I deleted the .m2 folder, Maven -> Clean and Maven -> Install. Exited STS, ran it again. And voila, everything works like a charm. Not a single error. Magic? I don't know.

Comment: you did not show the error here. so cannot help...   ans also the `spring-webmvc` is comming from the starter web. Do not add it there is no use.

Comment: give your controller class code && stactrace error

Comment: @wargre It is a compilation error stating that the type RequestMapping cannot be resolved.

Comment: @sajib It is a mere compilation error. There is not much code in the controller class. I just mention @ RequestMapping and there pops the compilation error.

Comment: where you use requestmapping

Comment: Sts gives strange problems. Did you try building using external Maven?

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba I have no idea about maven :( How do I run it externally?

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba Yes. STS indeed gives strange problems. I deleted the .m2 folder, Maven -> Clean and Maven -> Install. Exited STS, ran it again. And voila, everything works like a charm. Updated my question and answered too.

Comment: ... "Not a single error. Magic? I don't know." ... Actually it is quite a common occurrence for maven to somehow get its cache corrupted / broken. If you are getting seemingly nonsensical errors like... things you know for a fact exist cannot be found... Then, corrupted maven cache is often the reason. By cleaning out the cache you are forcing maven to re-download all the dependencies and that fixes the problem... so... no, it is not magic, though it may seem like that :-)